# Can't change persisted redux state

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-persist

I'm using Redux Persist to save the state of the app so that it's the same when it's closed and opened again. The initial states are saved successfully but I can't seem to update the persisted state with a action. My code is the following:

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import reducers from "./src/reducers";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import Router from "./src/Router";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
  debug: true
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

const store = createStore(persistedReducer);
const persistor = persistStore(store);

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <Router />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>
);

export default App;
```

**Schedule reducer**

```
import { strings } from "../../locales/i18n";
import * as types from "../actions/types";

const initialState = strings("schedule.list").map((item, index) => {
  return {
    key: index.toString(),
    title: item.title,
    time: item.time,
    location: item.location,
    description: item.description,
    isFavorite: false
  };
});

const scheduleReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.TOGGLE_FAVORITE:
      state.map(schedule => {
        if (schedule.key === action.id) {
          return (schedule.isFavorite = !schedule.isFavorite);
        }
      });
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default scheduleReducer;
```

I can see that the state of `isFavorite` changes when I call the action but when I reload the app it isn't persisted. What can be the issue here?

Comment: You should never mutate the state. If you need to update state, create a copy, update it and return the new state. Most probably redux-persist is not recognizing that the state has been changed.

Comment: Here are common patterns how to update redux state https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns. One of them is "updating an item in an array" https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-an-item-in-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` always creates a new array with the result of the callback function, take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). In your reducer, you are applying the `map` function but you are not holding any reference to the new array and returning the `existing state`, hence there is no change in the `state` and your state is not being persisted.

You can change your reducer as follows

```
const scheduleReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
  case types.TOGGLE_FAVORITE:
    cont updatedState = state.map(schedule => {
      if (schedule.key === action.id) {
        return { 
           ...schedule,
           isFavorite: !schedule.isFavorite 
        };
      }
      return schedule;
    });
    return updatedState;
  default:
    return state;
  }
};
```

Hope this will help!